# HTTPs Request Image really slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, backend

I have a function for getting images from a given https URL. Looking its performance I have reached that it takes around 20 seconds to finish executing... This is insane...

This is the code of the function I have implemented:

```
 function getImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
      // Profiling time
      const NS_PER_SEC = 1e9;
      const MS_PER_NS = 1e-6;
      const time = process.hrtime();


      const options = url.parse(imageUrl); // Automatically converted to an ordinary options object by https.request
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
          // Reject on bad status
          const { statusCode } = response;
          if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300) {
            return reject(new Error("Status Code:", statusCode));
          }

          // Cumulate data
          let chuncks = [];
          response.on("data", (chunck) => {
            chuncks.push(chunck);
          });

          // Resolve on end
          response.on("end", () => {
            // End time of execution
            const diff = process.hrtime(time);
            console.log(
              `Get image from url took ${
                (diff[0] * NS_PER_SEC + diff[1]) * MS_PER_NS
              } milliseconds`
            );

            resolve(Buffer.concat(chuncks));
          });
        });

        // Reject on request error
        request.on("error", (err) => {
          // This is not a "Second reject", just a different sort of failure
          reject(err.message);
        });

        // Close HTTP connection.
        request.end();
      });
    }
```

What I am doing wrong? Note that the requested url is https but doesn't have "www.". I don't thinks thats the problem, 20 seconds is too much time...

Any ideas? Is there any other better and easier way to handle this?

Comment: What is the actual `imageUrl` you are passing the function so we can run it ourselves against the same target?

Comment: Hmm, running your code here with node v14.4.0 on that URL takes 130ms.

Comment: This one https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tenedores-8115f.appspot.com/o/restaurant-images%2F0949dee7-79e5-458f-906b-ea8954926eb7?alt=media&token=c546f821-582e-4084-b527-edc8cf3bf85b

Comment: That one takes 801ms for me.

Comment: Okey the error is with the image size. I have tested with three images but for some reason my console only logged the first time (an image of 1.519.654 bytes)

Comment: I have no idea what that last comment means.  If you want us to help you debug your actual code when you're downloading three separate images, then show us THAT actual code that downloads three images with the actual URLs of the images.  There's nothing obviously wrong with the code in your question.

Comment: FYI, I use a higher level library such as `got()` for http/https downloads as it saves writing all this extra code.

Comment: I meant that I tested three images and always saw the same time in my terminal (I don't know why, think that was because the mouse was pressed in the terminal), that's why I give you this url. The only thing I do is just pass different urls to the function, but if the image is +1.5MB size (for example) it takes more than 20 seconds to get it. I have to look for an optimization.

Comment: Well, the issue is likely something to do with your environment, configuration or network because the code you show works just fine in a different environment. So, the answer is probably not about the code you show.

Comment: Okey!!! Thanks you!!!